# How to show an emails list in a page in Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, outlook-web-app

We are going to develop an interanet in sharepoint 2013. We would like to show a list containing emails (an overview on emails) in the home page, so it will be kinda a shortcut to outlook tab in sharepoint. It is just a list of emails and when the user click on one email, it will actually be opened in outlook in Sharepoint. This feature is for the user to have an overview of emails on his hoem page. I am checking for feasiblity of fetching emails and list them in first page. It would be great if anyone know if there is any out of box feature or any reference for how to code this feature.

Thanks

Comment: The questions is how i fetch emails from outlook?

Answer (score 0):

Just have a hyperlink like this in a Custom List or a Media and Content web part

```
<a href="mailto:email@email.com" />email@email.com</a><br />
<a href="mailto:email@email.com" />email@email.com</a><br />
```

etc

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I guess this is good in click event. My question is how i fetch emails to be able to show it as it is shown above.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint has a specific list template, called a Contacts list, for that.

First create a list based on the Contacts template, then in the ribbon use the "Connect to Outlook" feature.

Answer (score 0):

"SearchMailboxes" feature in EWS Managed API
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj221372(v=exchg.80).aspx